# Cannot start Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Cannot start jenkins. giving below logs when try to restart but doesnt work -

```
-bash-3.2$ ./jenkins.sh start
Jenkins is currently stopped...
Starting Jenkins with command cd     /eas/jenkins;/eas/jenkins/jenkins_jre/jre1.7.0_51/bin/java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -    XX:MaxPermSize=512m -DJENKINS_HOME=/eas/jenkins/home -jar jenkins.war
-bash-3.2$ standard in must be a tty
```

Please help!

Comment: Check [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/119376/bash-su-script-giving-an-error-standard-in-must-be-a-tty), not sure why you get the error in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

No, adding to sudoers file didnt solve it. there was issue with JVM where JDK was not able to initialize because of size I gave as arguments were not available, reduced and it worked.