# Gitlab Executor TTY

Tags: gitlab, tty

I'm trying to leverage Gitlab Runner to execute builds on remote machine. I have the runner and am using the shell executor to kick off builds locally. Unfortunately, I'm receiving the following error when I kick off something:

```
Using Shell executor...
standard in must be a tty
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I suspect this is occurring because the user that I'm passing in with the `--user` parameter can access tty. Any thoughts on how to get this working? The shell type is `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if GitLab is doing a sudo once connected to the remote machine, to change user.

If that is the case, with visudo (on that remote machine), do:

```
 Defaults:[username] !requiretty
```

If not, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36339999/6309), check if this is a JVM initialization issue.